# How to send info to phonegap app from URL

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Let's say I have an "Invite your friends" button.
The invite will simply be a link that will be able to be sent from different services e.g. email.
When a user clicks on the link the user needs to be able to either download the app or the app which is already installed will open and the app will receive specific data that is passed through the link.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Found what I was looking for!

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin